# CXF Dynamic Client getting Marshalling error

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, cxf

I am trying to convert a static CXF 2.5.4 client to one that is generated dynamically.  I have used the following code:

```
        JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
        logger.info("Dynamically loading wsdl from " + theWsdlLocation);
        dynClient = dcf.createClient(theWsdlLocation, bindingFileList);
        if (dynClient == null) {
            logger.severe("dynClient creation not successful");
        } else {
            logger.info("Successful creation of service client from wsdl at " + theWsdlLocation);
        }
        ......
        http = (HTTPConduit) dynClient.getConduit();
        HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
        ClassLoader clAfterClientPolicy = httpClientPolicy.getClass().getClassLoader();
        httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(36000);
        httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
        http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
        .......
        ClassLoader threadCL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        Object asrReq = threadCL.loadClass("com.microsoft.schemas.dynamics._2008._01.services.AddressServiceReadRequest").newInstance();
        .......
        Object [] asrRespObjs = dynClient.invoke("read", asrReq);
```

When the client launches the dynClient.invoke method, it throws the following Exception:

```
    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Marshalling Error: com.microsoft.schemas.dynamics._2008._01.services.AddressServiceReadRequest is not known to this context
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.marshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:261)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.write(DataWriterImpl.java:169)
```

Can anyone explain why JAXB cannot marshall the asrReq object?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to reset the Context Class Loader before loading your class like this:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassloader(threadCL);
```

as described:
[here](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/How-to-call-2-CXF-dynamic-clients-td5107299.html#a5119876)